# SQLDependency equivalent for MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#

I want to implement a real time update on my ASP.net project, so i tried to implement the long poling mechanism and Comet.

```
var isPolling = 0;
function longPolling()
{
    isPolling++;
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "CometAsyncHandler.ashx?waitTime=60", // one minute

     //async: true, 
     cache: false,
     //timeout:12000,

     success: function(data){ 
        isPolling--;
        if(data == "NEWDATAISAVAILABLE")
            RefreshData(); // this function is generated by using RegisterFunctionToPostBack()
        else if( data == "TOOLONG-DOITAGAIN" )
            setTimeout("longPolling()", 0 );
        else
            addLongPollingError("error", "Error on server side. Received data: \"" + data + "\"");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        isPolling--;
        addLongPollingError("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
    }
});
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  longPolling(); // Start the initial request 
});
```

I have successfully done that using SqlDependency class for MS SQL Database and it works but how to do this using MySQL DB.

Comment: Check this: [MySqlDependency](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to poll. While in theory you could leverage the [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html), I am not aware of any project that tries to achieve this.

See for example [`MySqlDependency`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html)