# Launch a notification from database

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to launch something like event, alert, or notification to all client from database server (mysql) when a specific value of a column in a table is under the standard.

This is not a web application to use javascript, I only must manage this using sql and c#.

```
 alert = AlertListner.getAlert();
 alert.launch(iduser);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395180/sqldependency-equivalent-for-mysql

Comment: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html

Comment: table trigger calls whatever proc you need to run when condition is met.

Comment: Probably the best way to do this is to have a middle tier service that sits between the database and the clients. All changes to the database are made by the clients asking the middle tier to make the change. The middle tier would also be responsible for raising an alert of the kind you want.

Comment: this middle tier is what exactly ? i use Client application that connect to same Database server