# Does RowChanged event on trigers when i make change in databse?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am learning databases with MySQL and C#. I am looking for way to respond to database changes so that users doesn't work with old data. Is the `RowChanged` event on `DataTable` object  triggered only when the `Row` object is changed or does it respond to changes to database table.

Comment: @TaW there is no SqlDependency object for MySQL; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26395181 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768609.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RowChanged` event will only be raised for local changes to the `Row`; it will not be raised if there are changes on the database server. MySQL Server doesn't support the server-side features necessary to make this possible. (The `SqlDependency` class, which is used for Microsoft SQL Server, is based on the [Service Broker infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server), which doesn't exist in MySQL.)

To get updates when the database is changed, you'll have to implement some sort of polling based on the shape of the data in your tables (e.g., does it have a `TIMESTAMP` column or some other value that always changes?); see [Update C# client whenever database is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768609).

Comment: Or create triggers, maybe to log changes to ease polling.